# showing list of directories using ls

Tags: linux, shell, ls, home-directory

I want to read all home directories of users on a Linux system.
I know I can use:

```
cut -d':' -f6 /etc/passwd | sort -u
```

to get a list of those directories.

How can I list each of those directories in detailed format, as when using `ls -l`?

For example, I would expect to get the root directory as:

> ```
> dr-xr-x---. 4 root root 4096 Mar  2 02:49 root
> ```

Is there any option to pipe the list from the `cut` command to `ls` for showing the content?

Comment: Yes, there are ways to pipe the list from cut to ls. What have you tried?

Comment: i tried direct pipe, withour xargs. that was my mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
cut -d':' -f6 /etc/passwd | sort -u | xargs -i% ls -ld %
```

Comment: If the home directories might contain spaces (unlikely, but possible!), then you should `xargs -d \\n` so that they are not split into separate arguments to `ls`.  I'm pretty sure the `passwd` file format doesn't permit embedded newlines, so you should be able to discount those.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following command line:

```
cut -d':' -f6 /etc/passwd | sort -u | xargs ls -ld
```